# sed command doesn't return what I want

Tags: bash, sed, ksh

My document doc.lst is compound with numbers and letters like this : 01 ABC and I want to take only the "ABC" part. I tried this, but it includes the numbers in my result.lst.

```
    sed -n -e '/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/p' < doc.lst > result.lst
```

How to delete those numbers?

Comment: I also tried this, but it doesn't work : sed -n -e '/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/p' | sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]/d' < doc.lst > result.lst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/p'
```

prints the lines that match that regexp.

Here, you'd want:

```
sed -n 's/.*\([[:upper:]]\{3\}\).*/\1/p'
```

That is, you want to substitute a sequence of any characters (as many as possible) followed by 3 uppercase letters (captured in `\1` with `\(...\)`) followed by a sequence of any characters with the captured letters and print the result of that substitution if it matches (the `p` flag of the `s` command).

Note that it will only print one set per line (the rightmost one).

To print all of them, you could do:

```
tr -cs '[:upper:]' '[\n*]' | grep -Ex '.{3}'
```

(note that with some `tr` implementations, it doesn't work properly with multi-byte characters).

The idea being to <kbd>tr</kbd>ansliterate <kbd>s</kbd>equences of the <kbd>c</kbd>omplement of <kbd>upper</kbd>case letters to newline characters, so that `tr`'s output contain all sequences of uppercase characters. Then you can do an e<kbd>x</kbd>act `grep` for the ones you're interested in.

On an input like `FOO BAR02 ABCDEF`, it would print:

```
FOO
BAR
```

While the previous solution would print `DEF`. If you have GNU `grep`, you could use its `-o` option:

```
grep -Eo '[[:upper:]]{3}'
```

Which would print:

```
FOO
BAR
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: I'll analyse this command because I don't understand every part. But thank's a lot, it works !

Comment: I've a problem because it doesn't include the AB1 and BB2. I'll try to edit your command but if you could give me the correct answer when you've time, that would be great

Comment: @JulienS, replace `[[:upper:]]\{3\}` with `[[:upper:]][[:upper:][:digit:]]\{2\}` if you want to include AB1, A12 but not 012 nor 0AA.

Comment: Just to know, Does `tr` support regex by default?

Comment: @heemayl, no, `tr` transliterates characters. You give it lists or ranges of characters.

Comment: Sometimes better remove unusual then replace all by usual `sed -n '/ [[:upper:]]\{2,\}[[:digit:]]*$/s/[0-9]* //p' < doc.lst > result.lst`

Answer (score 1):

For a list like...

```
01ABC
03BHG
2TG
```

...you can do a number of things.

Maybe most simply you can do:

```
sed 's/[^[:upper:]]\{1,\}/\n/g;/^\n/D'
```

...which would just substitute any sequence of chars which is not an uppercase letter for a `\n`ewline, and refrain from printing any results which afterward begin w/ a `\n`ewline *(though if uppercase letters remain they will still be printed)*.

If you have numbers following the uppercase letters that you wish to retain, you can try:

```
sed -n '/[[:upper:]]/s/[^[:upper:]]*//p'
```

...which would remove all non-uppercase letters from the head of a line which definitely contains an uppercase character and print the results. That will only work for one set per line, but based pn your comment - I guess that's all you've got?

Comment: I've also things like AB1 and your command doesn't give me AB1 but only AB. How to correct that?

Comment: @JulienS - I edited it to show how you might do it that way.